# can i push my modification directly to elementry os desktop repository ?

Tags: release-loki, elementary-project, repositories

i have viewed desktop code of elementary OS 
and i have some ideas for the desktop 
can i modify the code and push it directly ?
or there is a procedures that i have to do it first ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know where to begin, try the [developer guide](https://developer.elementary.io/) they provide, it helps a lot.

Unfortunately developing an OS don't work this way, you have to start a issue on [launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/elementary) or github (depending on the project you are working on), with the reasons why this feature should be implemented. If the team is OK with your feature you can start to code it, then the code reviewed and if it's according to the coding standard, it get implemented.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question , i am new in the open source environment if there is a place to get the fundamentals of the open source OS modifying  and how to get in ,  please provide me with it .